# Why does remix not use contract source code for debugging?

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

Remix is the only symbolic debugger I know (debugging line by solidity line instead of by instructions).

But sometimes like with [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf93ef71fa7c7d7686fb0ebfc7ac6fb512570614665aa2f324622f6942e37d5d0), the [matching source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x35792029777427920ce7adeccce9e645465e9c72#code) isn’t used for debugging, despite being compiled with the same compiler version.

How to force Remix to use a specific solidity source code (even if constructors don’t match) ?

Comment: You should request that feature in the remix github repo.

Comment: @Ismael it already exists. Just that sometimes (I don’t know why) the source code cannot be used. And anyway there’s no more bug fixes https://github.com/ethereum/remix/tree/master/remix-debugger